# Pandas method chaining with str.contains and str.split

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assign

I'm learning Pandas method chaining and having trouble using str.conains and str.split in a chain. The data is one week's worth of information scraped from a Wikipedia page, I will be scraping several years worth of weekly data.

This code without chaining works:

```
#list of data scraped from web:
list = ['Unnamed: 0','Preseason-Aug 11','Week 1-Aug 26','Week 2-Sep 2',
       'Week 3-Sep 9','Week 4-Sep 23','Week 5-Sep 30','eek 6-Oct 7','Week 7-Oct 14',
       'Week 8-Oct 21','Week 9-Oct 28','Week 10-Nov 4','Week 11-Nov 11','Week 12-Nov 18',
       'Week 13-Nov 25','Week 14Dec 2','Week 15-Dec 9','Week 16 (Final)-Jan 4','Unnamed: 18']

#load to dataframe:

df = pd.DataFrame(list)

#rename column 0 to text:
df = df.rename(columns = {0:"text"})

#remove ros that contain "Unnamed":
df = df[~df['text'].str.contains("Unnamed")]

#split column 0 into 'week' and 'released' at the hyphen:
df[['week', 'released']] = df["text"].str.split(pat = '-', expand = True)
```

Here's my attempt to rewrite it as a chain:

```
#load to dataframe:

df = pd.DataFrame(list)

#function to remove rows that contain "Unnamed"
def filter_unnamed(df):
    df = df[~df["text"].str.contains("Unnamed")]
    return df

clean_df = (df
            .rename(columns = {0:"text"})
            .pipe(filter_unnamed)
             #[['week','released']] = lambda df_:df_["text"].str.split('-', expand = True)
)
```

The first line of the clean_df chain to rename column 0 works.

The second line removes rows that contain "Unnamed"; it works, but is there a better way than using pipe and a function?

I'm having the most trouble with str.split in the 3rd row (doesn't work, commented out). I tried assign for this and think it should work, but I don't know how to pass in the new column names ("week" and "released") with the str.split function.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: First thing, I wouldn't name a variable 'list', because it's a keyword in Python. Rather, `list1` or something.

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't figure out how to create two columns in one go from the split... but I was able to do it by splitting twice and accessing parts 1 and 2 in succession (not ideal), `df.assign(week = ...[0], released = ...[1])`.

Note also I reset the index.

```
df.assign(week = df[0].str.split(pat = '-', expand=True)[0], released = df[0].str.split(pat = '-', expand=True)[1])[~df[0].str.contains("Unnamed")].reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns = {0: "text"})
```

I'm sure there's a sleeker way, but this may help.

Comment: Thank you, this helps me get it into the chain, which I wasn't able to do before.